# The least squares estimators $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are uncorrelated.

Tags: regression, linear-regression

Consider the simple linear regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim\ \text{NID}(0,\sigma^2)$.

Show that the least squares estimators $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are uncorrelated.

My attempt:

Since $\hat{\beta_0}=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1\bar{x}}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}=\dfrac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}}=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{x_i-\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1})&=\text{Cov}(\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1\bar{x}}, \hat{\beta_1})\\
&=\text{Cov}(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1})-\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1\bar{x}},\hat{\beta_1})\\
&=\text{Cov}(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1})-\bar{x}\cdot\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1\bar{x}},\hat{\beta_1})\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(\bar{y}, \hat{\beta_1})&=\text{Cov}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i,\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}y_i\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}\cdot\text{Var}(y_i)\\
&=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}\qquad \text{,Var($y_i$)$=\sigma^2$}\\
&=0\qquad, \text{Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}=0$}  
\end{aligned}$$

Also,
$$\begin{aligned}
\bar{x}\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1},\hat{\beta_1})&=\bar{x}\text{Var}(\hat{\beta_1})\\
&=\bar{x}\cdot\frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}\qquad, \text{Since $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta_1})=\frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}$}  
\end{aligned}$$
Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1})&=0-\frac{\bar{x}\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
\end{aligned}$$
How to conclude that $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ are uncorrelated? if they are not equal to $0$.

Comment: They are not uncorrelated in general.

Comment: how to show that they are uncorrelated